# Changing route doesn't scroll to specified position immediately in the new page

Tags: angularjs, scroll, controller

I have 2 views/controller. While destroying `controller1` I'm storing `controller1`'s data-list and scroll position in a service and redirecting to `controller2`.

When coming back to `controller1` from ``controller2, I'm fetching controller1`'s data-list and scroll position from service and loading all the previously loaded data along with scroll directly to the previously stored position.

What should happen is, it should directly jump to that position instead of scrolling from top to scroll position.(But, problem is its scrolling from top to the stored scroll position.)

Any solution to this?

Comment: Please create a [MCVE] that demonstrates the behavior that you are seeing.

Comment: ok.. 'll create one and update here.

Answer (score 0):

try like the below,

> $window.scrollTo(0, 0);

```
//service    
this.scrollPositioning= function (param) {
    if (angular.isDefined(param)) {
        $window.scrollTo(0, isNaN(param) ? $(param).offset().top : param);
    }
};
```

Here the **param** can be the position value

```
//ex. 100 or 700 (y axis) 
//service.scrollPositioning(800);
```

Or

It can be the **CSS Class Name** of your ui-view where it can be locate in the window and to scroll to that particular position.

```
//ex. <ui-view class="nesterViewDiv">
//service.scrollPositioning('nesterViewDiv');
```